# canvas layer ordering in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas, google-maps-api-3, html5-canvas

Google Maps utility library comes with a full map canvas overlay[1] which is pretty useful to create canvas based visualizations or custom layers (instead of the tiled based ones)

The problem is that CanvasLayer is based on an OverlayView and it has to be on top of all the map layers. My questions are:

- Is there a way to place an overlay in between two layers (i.e tiled layers) ?
- Is there a better way to implement a full map canvas layer which can be managed in the same way other layers are? (using overlayMapTypes).

For sure there are nasty hacks that can be done changing the DOM to sort layers and overlays but I'd prefer to do in a way it won't break when the internal implementation was changed.

[1] https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/canvaslayer/src/CanvasLayer.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by  "map-layers" , but when you mean the [mapPanes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#MapPanes)  :

A `CanvasLayer` is not placed on top of all `mapPanes`, by default it's placed in the `overlayLayer`-pane(which is the 2nd lowest pane of the 7 `mapPanes`).

But it must not be placed there, you may place it where you want to by using the `paneName`-option of the `canvasLayerOptions`(set it to any valid `mapPanes`-name)